# How to pass exact value of textbox from one page to another

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written a C# code to pass `TextBox` value of one page to another.

```
Response.Redirect("SubmittedSuccessfullt.aspx?" + TextBox56.Text.ToString());
```

`TextBox56` has value `SJS/187/2000` but when the value is passed to another page and I print it using a `Label` it get printed like `SJS%2f187%2f2000`.

In the redirected page I have written code in the following way:

```
Label24.Text = Request.QueryString.ToString();
```

Please suggest me how can I exactly pass the value of `TextBox` to another page and can get the exact value in another page.

Comment: Looks to me like you have to HtmlEncode your string. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: or encode it to a base64 string prior to appending it to the query string, and decode on next page.

Comment: You may want to consider renaming your controls as well...  Will you really remember what `TextBox56` is for next week/

Answer (score 5):

You must **encode** the value before passing it to next page. like this:

```
Response.Redirect("second.aspx?Parameter=" + Server.UrlEncode(TextBox1.Text));
Label1.Text = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["Parameter"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

try using your code like this :

```
Label24.Text = Request.QueryString["Parameter"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string text = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(TextBox56.Text);
Response.Redirect("SubmittedSuccessfullt.aspx?" + text);
```

Your text should now be encoded to not be parsed as html.